# Dynamics/CDS Single line of text format options Phone custom telephony provider

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365, common-data-service

**TL;DR**

Instead of opening this Launch Application window on desktop, I'd like the button to run custom code to open a new tab in my browser or pop window in my browser. Is that possible?

**Full Context**

In Dynamics and Power Apps there's a Phone option included in the Single line of text format options. This provides a nice user experience to click a phone icon along the text icon to launch a desktop application or phone app on mobile to make a call.

Is it possible to create a a custom action for this phone call button using my own code? Maybe in JavaScript.

"[In the web application, fields will be click-enabled to initiate calls using either Skype or Lync if a client for either is installed on your computer. The telephony provider choice is at the bottom of the General tab of System Settings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/types-of-fields#single-line-of-text-format-options)" It's seems the only customization supported are in system settings and it only allows you to define the Skype provider.

[image]

Ideally when using Dynamics in browser I would like to click the phone call button and instead of a Launch Application window, give the user a pop up I serve in browser using my own code to handle the phone call action. Is that possible?

[image]

I do not want the below to open, instead I want my own code to perform a custom action like open a pop up window in browser or alert dialog in browser.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly that way by default:
[image]

You probably set that "Remember my choice for tel links." once in the past. You can change default app for tel: links in Windows settings.

There is no supported way to run custom javascript by clicking action icon. But this code snippet should do the trick. Run it on form load:

```
MscrmControls.FieldControls.PhoneNumberControl.prototype.action = function() { debugger; };
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, instead of opening this Launch Application window on desktop, I'd like the button to run custom code to open a new tab in my browser or pop window in my browser. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi. I updated answer. It's hack and may break in the future.